# Illegal invocation for sending data with POST with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the excelPrintarea and post that data to my Employees controller. But when I add the data and datatype attribute it tells me it's an illegal invocation. I don't understand why it is saying that.

Also when I leave the data, datetype and POST out the downloadExcel from my employees controller does fire.

```
function printExcel() {
    var excelPrintarea = document.getElementById('printarea');
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>employees/downloadExcel",
        data: {myPrintArea: excelPrintarea},
        dateType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function(excelPrintarea) {
            alert("printing excel worked")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You've put an element in the object. jQuery is then trying to serialise that object to a string - hence the error. Presumably this is a mistake and you need to get the required *property* from the element instead

Comment: I think your comment helped me out. I used  document.getElementById('printarea').innerHTML. But now it says bad request (400) instead of illegal invocation. Thank you Rory.

Comment: That's progress. A 400 response means that the AJAX request is now being made, but the recipient is rejecting it for some reason. If you can find the request details in the console there should hopefully be more information - or, if you have control of the server, you can check the logs and/or logic flow